# Variable expected

Tags: java, variables, increment

```
private void calculateForEachQuestion() {
    ...
    if (questions.size() >= answers.size()) {
        answers.forEach(answer -> {
            if (questions.contains(answer))
                this.answer.setPoints((this.answer.getPoints())++);
                // Variable expected  ^                    
    });
}
```

The error I encountered is:

> unexpected type
>   required: variable
>   found: value

What is wrong with the statement?

```
this.answer.setPoints((this.answer.getPoints())++);
```

Comment: You should include the exact error you're seeing.

Comment: If postincrement works the same in Java as it does in C (quite likely) then *even if the syntax was correct*, you'd still end up with the same value ...

Comment: I don't think you can use `++` on a value, it expects a variable.  Try `+1` instead.

Comment: It seems like you have misunderstood what `this` means.

Comment: Why not just write `answer.setPoints(answer.getPoints()+1);`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `++` operator only makes sense when applied to a declared variable.

This operator will add one to an `integer`, `long`, etc. and save the result to the same variable in-place.

If there is no declared variable, there is nowhere to save the result, which is why the compiler complains.

One way to allow use of the `++` operator in this situation would be (not the most concise code, but to illustrate the point):

```
int myVariable = this.answer.getPoints();
myVariable++;
this.answer.setPoints(myVariable);
```

Answer (score 6):

`this.answer.getPoints()` will return a value, and you can't use increment `++` or decrement `--` on that. You can only use it on variables.

If you want to add 1 to it, you can do it as:

```
this.answer.setPoints((this.answer.getPoints())+1);
```

---

> I know that, but why?

You can do this:

```
int x = 5;
x++; // x is a variable and can have value 6
```

but not this:

```
5++; // 5 is a value and can't have value 6
```

Answer (score 4):

Change this:

```
this.answer.setPoints((this.answer.getPoints())++);
```

to:

```
this.answer.setPoints((this.answer.getPoints())+1);
```

`++` will increment a variable with 1, but since `this.answer.getPoints()` will return a value and its not a defined variable, it won't be able to store the incremented value.

Think of it like doing:
`this.answer.getPoints() = this.answer.getPoints() + 1`, where would the incremented value be stored?

Comment: Why not omit `this`? It is totally unnecessary, is it not?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko because you can't modify the return value of a method, and `++` modifies the variable it's used on?

Answer (score 1):

The error is just in this bit:

```
(this.answer.getPoints())++
```

The first part of this `(this.answer.getPoints())` creates an rvalue: effectively, an anonymous variable that lasts almost no time.

The second part `++` increments that anonymous variable *after* it is passed into `setPoints()`.

Then, the anonymous variable (now incremented) is thrown away.

The compiler/IDE knows that you're doing something that will never be used (incrementing a temporary value), and is flagging it.